# C# Countdown Timer to chosen date from now

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, countdown

SharpDevelope / WPF Application

For now i got a working program.
What does it do?

It‘s a gridlistview with several entries for reminders.
Columns as followed:

Entry time / date / time / case / description / priority / name who entered / case closed? (as combobox)

So my actual problem:
I want to implement a countdown timer function to the given date and time.
So if someone check the combobox(to create a countdown) while making an entry, the program should create a timer.

I searched several threads here and on other sites, but cant find a good solution.

What should it do when button „add entry to list“ is pressed and the „create timer“ combobox is checked?

Create timer from the date.textbox and time.textbox combined (i cant get it right for a valid datetime). So for me it would be "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss".

Then substract the combined date from timeNow() and display the remaining time till 0 in a textbox beside the gridview.
I don't know if it would be to much if there are xxx amounts of timers created by entries.

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: What kind of app is this? WinForms, WPF, Unity, some kind of web app?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot. I use SharpDevelope. It‘s a WPF application.

Comment: https://wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/